# Can't create a new component via angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've recently upgraded to angular cli 1.4.3. Now all of a sudden I can't make new components using (for example):

```
ng g c another --flat
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@schematics\angular\package.json'
```

Anyone else had this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when you generate a new project and haven't installed all the modules (like package.json),

make sure you run `npm install` on any new projects, and install any missing modules after that.

this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Some lovely person has just fixed this in version 1.4.4.
Thank you who ever you are :)